# Converting FileConfiguration to a File

Tags: java

I currently have a FileConfiguraton Object:

```
FileConfiguration fc = plugin.dfs.getCustomConfig();
```

How could I change this FileConfiguration Object into a regular File Object?

I've tried casting File to it like so:

```
File f = (File) plugin.dfs.getCustomConfig();
```

But that is not possible.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Where is the definition for `FileConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileConfiguration getFile() method.

```
File f = fc.getFile();
```